# Add Inbound Rule(s) to multiple EC2 Instances / Security Groups at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-vpc

Within AWS, is there a way to add 1 or multiple Inbound Rules across multiple EC2 Instances or Security Groups at once?

Example:

I would like to add 124.1.0.0/24 to over 70+ EC2 Instances at once, rather than having to go to each AWS EC2 Instance or Security Group and manually inputting the rule 70+ times.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

I've tried adding the Inbound Rule manually (which works) but want to find a quicker way.

Would this work below? Sorry not to well versed in Python yet.

```
import boto 
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2() 
sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups(group_ids='sg-1', 'sg-2', 'sg-3', ..... 'sg-71')[0] 
sg.authorize(ip_protocol="-1", from_port=3389, to_port=None, cidr_ip="124.1.0.0/24", src_group=None, dry_run=False)
```

Comment: Script it with awscli or, for example, a Python script. Or look at the features of [AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/).

Comment: If this is for a port/protocol that you already allow and you are just adding a new source CidrIp address and it is something you might need to do semi-regularly you could look at changing your security group rules to use a Managed Prefix List. That way your source is the prefix list and you update that in one place and all security groups will honour the change. [AWS Managed Prefix Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html)

Comment: @jarmod

Would this work? Please see below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736846/how-to-add-inbound-rules-for-aws-ec2-security-group-for-all-traffic

Comment: That examples modifies a single security group to allow all traffic from all source IPs. Not a good idea, typically. But the code does show you how to do it so you can create your own variant of the code that enumerates security groups and then applies ingress rules as needed.

Comment: @jarmod Would this work below? Sorry not to well versed in Python yet. 

import boto
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups(group_ids='sg-1', 'sg-2', 'sg-3', ..... 'sg-71')[0]
sg.authorize(ip_protocol="-1", from_port=3389, to_port=None, cidr_ip="124.1.0.0/24", src_group=None, dry_run=False)

Comment: Simplest might be to use [client.authorize_security_group_ingress(...)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress). Importantly: use boto3, not boto. Also, if you're allowing ingress on port N, then both FromPort and ToPort should be set to N. Try writing some code and run it against a test AWS account.